# How to pass value to view from form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Good day.
The challenge is:
Create a form that will change the parameters of the model fields, based on user input.

My logic is this. I tried to create a form for entering changes:
In the lists , I recorded all the ID and field names of the model;

```
class RefDataForm(forms.Form):
        NODE_ID_LIST=[('YE102_4G','YE102_4G'),('AG001_4G','AG001_4G')]
        ANRFUNC_PARAM_LIST=[('zzztemporary7','zzztemporary7'),('zzztemporary2','zzztemporary2')]

        change_id                       =       forms.CharField(label='Node ID for Change', widget=forms.Select(choices=NODE_ID_LIST))
        change_param_name               =       forms.CharField(label='Parameter name for Change', widget=forms.Select(choices=ANRFUNC_PARAM_LIST))
        value                           =       forms.CharField(label='Value')
```

Next in view.py, I'm trying to create a *.update* command that should accept changes.

```
def ref_test(request, template_name ='ref_test.html'):

   if request.method == 'POST':
        test=RefDataForm(request.POST)

        if test.is_valid():
            change_id          = request.POST['change_id']
            change_param_name  = request.POST['change_param_name']
            change_value       = request.POST['value']


            update_form        = Ran4GRfAnrfunction.objects.filter(pk__in=change_id).update(change_param_name=change_value)
    else:
        test=RefDataForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'test':test})
```

My html is :

```
<form  method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

                {{ test.change_id }}
                {{ test.change_param_name }}
                {{ test.value }}

<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

However, I get an error

***Ran4GRfAnrfunction has no field named 'change_param_name' ***

How do I pass field_name through a form?

In manage.py shell, I tried to do it - and its work.

```
from dumper.models import *
change_id = ['AG001_4G', 'AG002_4G']
change_value = ('Okay')
change_param_name = ('zzztemporary2')
Ran4GRfAnrfunction.objects.filter (pk__in = change_id) .update (zzztemporary2 = change_value)
```

How do I pass the value of **change_param_name**  to **.update** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've already figured this out since the questions been here for five hours at this point.

I can't exactly test this, but it looks like your problem is right here. This line is telling it to change the `change_param_name` field - not to change the field matching the name stored in `change_param_name`.

```py
.update(change_param_name=change_value)
```

You should be able to fix this by putting the values into a dictionary and unpacking it.

```py
.update(**{change_param_name: change_value})
```